# Logo image and H1 heading on the same line

Tags: html, css, position, inline

I want to create my first web page but I encountered a problem.

I have the following code:

```
<img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo" />
<h1>My website name</h1>
```

I'd like to know how to make the logo and the H1 to be in the same line.
Thanks!

Answer (score 114, accepted):

As example ([DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5Gy6K/)):

HTML:

```
<div class="header">
  <img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo" />
  <h1>My website name</h1>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.header img {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #555;
}

.header h1 {
  position: relative;
  top: 18px;
  left: 10px;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5Gy6K/)

Comment: @Speransky Got almost same.. ;)

Comment: @SperanskyDanil You deserve it too am upvoting you, you missed out the `line-height` and `clear` I guess

Answer (score 25):

If your image is part of the logo why not do this:

```
<h1><img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo" /> My website name</h1>
```

Use CSS to style it better.

And it is also best practice to make your logo a hyperlink that take the user back to the home page.

So you could do:

```
<h1 id="logo"><a href="/"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo" /> My website name</a></h1>
```

Comment: Is is "legal" per HTML specification?

Answer (score 22):

Try this:

1. Put both elements in a container DIV.
2. Give that container the property overflow:auto
3. Float both elements to the left using float:left
4. Give the H1 a width so that it doesn't take up the full width of it's parent container.

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
<img style="display: inline;" src="img/logo.png" alt="logo" />
<h1 style="display: inline;">My website name</h1>
```

Answer (score 7):

Just stick the img tag inside the h1 tag as part of the content.

Comment: @Kermit It's pretty self explanatory and worked for me!

Answer (score 4):

you can do this by using just one line code..

```
<h1><img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo"/>My website name</h1>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it as Billy Moat told you, wrap your `<img>` and `<h1>` in a `<div>` and use `float: left;` to float your image to the left, set the `<div>` `width` and than set a `line-height` for your `h1` and use `<div style="clear: float;"></div>` to clear your floating elements.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bvGeG/1/)**

Answer (score 3):

I'd use bootstrap and set the html as:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <h1>My website name</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my code without any div within the header tag. My goal/intention is to implement the same behavior with minimal HTML tags and CSS style. It works.

**whois.css**

```
.header-img {
    height: 9%;
    width: 15%;
}

header {
    background: dodgerblue;

}

header h1 {
    display: inline;
}
```

**whois.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title> Javapedia.net WHOIS Lookup </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="whois.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <img class="header-img" src ="javapediafb.jpg" alt="javapedia.net" href="https://www.javapedia.net"/>
        <h1>WHOIS Lookup</h1>
    </header>
</body>
```

output:
[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

in your css file do `img { float: left; }` and `h1 {float: left; }`

Answer (score 0):

Check this.

```
 .header{width:100%;
    }

    .header img{ width: 20%; //or whatever width you like to have

    }

    .header h1{

    display:inline; //It will take rest of space which left by logo.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<head>
<style>
header{
    color: #f4f4f4;
    background-image: url("header-background.jpeg");    
}

header img{
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
}

header h1{
    font-size: 40px; 
    color: #f4f4f4;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px 20px 0 0;
    display: inline-block;
}
</style></head>


<header>
<a href="index.html">
    <img src="./branding.png" alt="technocrat logo" height="100px" width="100px"></a>
    <a href="index.html">
    <h1><span> Technocrat</span> Blog</h1></a>
</div></header>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Steps:

1. Surround both the elements with a container div.
2. Add `overflow:auto` to container div.
3. Add `float:left` to the first element.
4. Add `position:relative; top: 0.2em; left: 24em` to the second element (Top and left values can vary according to you).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow @Richa It is always better to `include` the `source` or `references` in support of your answer and If possible provide `why` your answer works...